# Broken link on help page: “How do I write a good question?”

Tags: bug, broken-link

On the Stack Overflow help page [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) there appears to be a broken link: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (well, at least the domain is for sale).

I searched on Google and the top result (at least for me) is [this Google cached page](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/). I also checked the Internet archive, and it [was active 11/13/2017](http://web.archive.org/web/20171113093102/https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Should the link be updated to that cached Google page?

Comment: I am not able to access the google cached page link...[here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is what i can access

Comment: URL is still on Eric's profile too, and he was active in the last 5 hours, someone might want to let him know his domain registry expired.

Comment: The link appears to be working now.